# Compressing and decompressing a string yields only the first letter of the original string?

Tags: c#, gzipstream

I'm compressing a string with Gzip using this code:

```
public static String Compress(String decompressed)
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(decompressed);
        using (var input = new MemoryStream(data))
        using (var output = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var gzip = new GZipStream(output, CompressionMode.Compress, true))
            {
                input.CopyTo(gzip);
            }
            return Convert.ToBase64String(output.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

and decompressing it with this code:

```
    public static String Decompress(String compressed)
    {
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(compressed);
        using (MemoryStream input = new MemoryStream(data))
        using (GZipStream gzip = new GZipStream(input, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
        {
            gzip.CopyTo(output);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (byte b in output.ToArray())
                sb.Append((char)b);
            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
```

When I use these functions in this sample code, the result is only the letter `S`:

```
String test = "SELECT * FROM foods f WHERE f.name = 'chicken';";
String com = Compress(test);
String decom = Decompress(com);
Console.WriteLine(decom);
```

If I debug the code, I see that the value of `decom` is

```
S\0E\0L\0E\0C\0T\0 \0*\0 \0F\0R\0O\0M\0 \0f\0o\0o\0d\0s\0 \0f\0 \0W\0H\0E\0R\0E\0 \0f\0.\0n\0a\0m\0e\0 \0=\0 \0'\0c\0h\0i\0c\0k\0e\0n\0'\0;\0
```

but the value displayed is only the letter `S`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These lines are the problem:

```
foreach (byte b in output.ToArray())
    sb.Append((char)b);
```

You are interpreting each byte as its own character, when in fact that is not the case. Instead, you need the line:

```
string decoded = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(output.ToArray());
```

which will convert the byte array to a string, based on the encoding.

The basic problem is that you are converting to a byte array based on an encoding, but then ignoring that encoding when you retrieve the bytes. As well, you may want to use `Encoding.UTF8` instead of `Encoding.Unicode` (though that shouldn't matter, as long as the encodings match up.)

Comment: That fixed it. I changed `Encoding.Unicode` to `Encoding.UTF8` throughout both methods as well, just to be safe. Thank you! I'll accept once the delay expires.

Answer (score 1):

In your compress method replace Unicode with UTF8:

```
byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(decompressed);
```